# Simulating Torsion Springs

Tags: python, simulation, physics

Probably a bit more of a physics question than a programming question...
Basically I am trying to simulate a robot with a torsion spring in its knee (see picture) and measure what forces are applied to the knee joint and how much the spring deforms.

[picture of robot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMw2W.png)

The program I've written produces graphs that have the correct shape, but for some reason the angle of the spring seems to be scaling with the size of my timesteps, which is definitely not correct.

I have attached my code below, but here is also a detailed explanation of what I think I am doing:

I assume that besides gravitation, there is only one force ever applied to the robot, and that force is applied at the start for a certain duration and is aimed straight down. From that force I calculate the angular velocity of my joint.

After that, I enter a loop where in every timestep I update the forces and the angle of the spring. I calculate the gravitational force dependent on the angle. I assume that my model resembles an inverted pendulum, and that the term for the mass of the leg is negligible. Then I calculate the counterforce exerted by the spring, and get the total force from the difference between the two.

I calculate the velocity change from the force, and update the velocity. From the velocity I get the change in angle and update the angle as well. I repeat that loop until a time limit is reached.

The rest of the code is just for plotting.

For some reason, the scale of the angle changes drastically with the size of the timesteps I choose. Other than that, however, the graphs look as I would expect: Oscillating briefly and then settling on one value. One problem I see is that the force of the spring directly depends on the timestep, while the gravitational force does not. Since everything else depends on the difference between the two forces, this changes the scale. However, I do not know how to fix this.

Thanks for any help!

```
import math
from scipy import constants
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Spring:
    def __init__(self, k, l=0.17, m=6.0):
        self.k = k
        self.l = l
        self.m = m
        self.alphaplt = []
        self.forceplt = []

    def impulse(self, force, duration, at_angle, stept):
        time = 0
        alpha = at_angle
        i = self.m * self.l ** 2
        vk = (force / self.m * duration) / self.l
        while time <= 100:
            tm = 0.5 * self.m * constants.g * self.l * math.sin(alpha)
            tf = self.k * vk * stept / self.l
            tg = tm - tf
            vk = vk + (tg * stept * self.l) / i
            alpha = alpha + vk * stept
            time += stept
            self.alphaplt.append(alpha)
            self.forceplt.append(tg)

        plt.plot(self.alphaplt)
        plt.show()
        plt.plot(self.forceplt)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Spring(0.75)
    s.impulse(90, 0.5, 0, 0.01)
```

Comment: First off, you should plot your `alpha` and `force` with respect to time - right now you're using the number of iterations as your independent variable, so it's difficult to compare plots between the two cases.

Also, your code is inconsistent with your description - it looks like you're applying your "applied at the start for a certain duration" force throughout the whole run. You'd need some `if` statement to verify if you should still be applying it, or whether `tf` should be 0.

I don't see why the spring force should depend on the timestep, so... check your math!

Comment: A general tip for any kind of physical simulation problem... Always label your plot axes, always check your equations, always check the units used!

Comment: I am not convinced your physics model is correct. Is this supposed to be moving only up and down, i.e. does the system have only one degree of freedom? You have complicated interaction, and you have two potential forces, gravity and torsion spring, plus one external force (I assume constant magnitude), which acts for a period of time and them stops. The model that comes out of this seems to be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see an animated simulation of this system, go to
[Online VPython's webpage](https://glowscript.org/), register (it's free), paste the script I have written below and run it. Some explanations of the code are written included as comments in the script

```py
Web VPython 3.2

# system of differential equations of the mathematical model of the physical system:
def f(state, param, F):
    m, L, k, theta_0, g = param
    a = state.x
    p = state.y
    s_a = sin(a)
    c_a = cos(a)
    da_dt = p / (s_a**2)
    dp_dt = c_a * p**2 / (s_a**3) - (k/(2*m*L**2)) * (2*a + theta_0 - pi) + ((g + F/m) / (2*L)) * s_a 
    return vector(da_dt, dp_dt, 0.) 

# one Runge-Kutta time-step propagation of the system's dynamics:
def propagate_RK4(f, state, param, F, dt):
    k1 = f(state, param, F)
    k2 = f(state + dt*k1/2., param, F)
    k3 = f(state + dt*k2/2., param, F)
    k4 = f(state + dt*k3, param, F)
    return state + dt*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4) / 6.

# transforming the dynamical variable angle into the actual, physical configuration of the system 
def configure(struct, state):
    struct[0].pos = vector( L*sin(state.x), L*cos(state.x), 0. )
    struct[1].pos = vector( 0.,  2*L*cos(state.x), 0. )
    struct[2].axis = struct[0].pos 
    struct[3].pos = struct[0].pos
    struct[3].axis = struct[1].pos - struct[0].pos
    return None


# initialization and animation of the system's dynamics:

# constant parameters of the model: 
m=6.0
L=0.17
k=55.75
theta_0 = 2*pi/3
g = 9.8
F = 150.
param = (m, L, k, theta_0, g)
a_0 = pi/10

# fixed location of the lowest, ground level, joint: 
sphere(pos = vector(0., 0., 0.), radius = .005, color=color.red)
 
# initial positions of the moving middle joint, where the torsion spring is
joint_1 = sphere(pos = vector(L*sin(a_0), L*cos(a_0), 0.), radius = .01, color=color.red, make_trail=True)

# initial positions of the upper joint, where the main load (box) is positioned
joint_2 = sphere(pos = vector(0., 2*L*cos(a_0), 0. ), radius = .01, color=color.red, make_trail=True)

# initial configuration of the bar between ground joint and joint 1
bar_01 = cylinder(pos=vector(0,0,0), axis=vector(0, L,0), radius=0.003, color=color.orange)

# initial configuration of the bar between ground joint and joint 2
bar_12 = cylinder(pos=vector(0,L,0), axis=vector(0,L,0), radius=0.003, color=color.orange)

# initial state of the system, given by an initial angle a_0:
state = vector(a_0, 0., 0.)
t = 0.
dt = 0.01
force_duration = 0.7
frame_rate = 15
force_duration = force_duration / frame_rate

# drawing in yellow the locations of joint 1 and 2 at time t=0 
sphere(pos = vector(L*sin(a_0), L*cos(a_0), 0.), radius = .005, color=color.yellow)
sphere(pos = vector(0., 2*L*cos(a_0), 0. ), radius = .005, color=color.yellow)

# animation of the dynamics of the system while the constant external force is acting: 
while t <= force_duration:
    rate(frame_rate)
    state = propagate_RK4(f, state, param, F, dt)
    configure([joint_1, joint_2, bar_01, bar_12], state)
    t=t+dt

# drawing in yellow the locations of joint 1 and 2 at the time moment when the external force stops acting
sphere(pos = vector(L*sin(state.x), L*cos(state.x), 0.), radius = .005, color=color.yellow)
sphere(pos = vector(0., 2*L*cos(state.x), 0. ), radius = .005, color=color.yellow)

# animation of the dynamics of the system  after the constant external force has stopped acting: 
while force_duration < t <= 10:
    rate(frame_rate)
    state = propagate_RK4(f, state, param, 0, dt)
    configure([joint_1, joint_2, bar_01, bar_12], state)
    t=t+dt
```